Capture groups within an f-string in Python Polars
I am trying to convert a series like this
s = pl.Series(['{1-5}', '1'])

to a series like this
pl.Series(['{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}', '1'])

which I can do if I manually write the 1 and 5 corresponding to the extrema of the first element, i.e.
s.str.replace(r'\{(\d+)-(\d+)\}', f'{set(range(1, 6))}')

but I want to refer to the capture groups instead, e.g. something like
s.str.replace(r'\{(\d+)-(\d+)\}', f'{set(range(int('${1}'), int('${2}' + 1)))}')

How can I do this?

You can't refer to capture groups in the replacement parts of an f-string. The f-string is expanded before the function is called.

Is there any other way I can convert these occurrences of '{x-y}' to strings '{x, x+1, ..., y -1, y}'?

In Pandas, the replacement can be a function, it receives the capture groups in the arguments. The Polars documentation doesn't mention this possibility, though.

As the $1 expansion happens at the Rust level, there is no way to use the expanded value "programatically" with .str.replace()
You could extract the parts you want and use them in Polars expressions:
df = s.to_frame()

digits = pl.all().str.extract_groups(r"[{](\d+)-(\d+)[}]")

df.with_columns(
   pl.format("{{}}",
      pl.int_ranges(digits.struct["1"], digits.struct["2"].cast(int) + 1)
        .cast(pl.List(pl.String))
        .list.join(", ")
   )
   .fill_null(pl.all()) # use original value if no regex match
   .alias("result")
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬─────────────────┐
│       ┆ result          │
│ ---   ┆ ---             │
│ str   ┆ str             │
╞═══════╪═════════════════╡
│ {1-5} ┆ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} │
│ 1     ┆ 1               │
└───────┴─────────────────┘

